# Is there a way to enumerate Public Folder permissions on Exchange 2003?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, vbscript, public-folders

My organisation is about to start the process of migrating from Exchange 2003 to 2010. However we have a large number of public folders and in order to maintain functionality for users need to somehow enumerate the permissions of each public folder so that we can identify public folders that can be migrated in conjunction with their associated users.

So does anyone know of some way to get a list of public folders and their associated permissions from exchange 2003?

Is there a way to get the info using the WMI Public Folders class?

I've already had a quick look at PFDAVAdmin tool and will be testing this as soon as possible but if someone has experience with it can you tell me if it will do what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to install [PFDAVDadmin from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=635BE792-D8AD-49E3-ADA4-E2422C0AB424&displaylang=en).  It allows all kinds of access/insight into the murky depths of Exchange.  Among other things, it will allow you to export permissions of your public folders (but it does so much more...)

It's ugly and a little obtuse.  Read the instructions (link to the FM on the linked download page.)

Comment: Thanks, I've had a chance to try it out and it works a treat!